Animation is not working after first iteration
I am trying to animate a paragraph and an arrow, I am trying to explain my animation here:

the paragraph div will appear smoothly
with slight delay the arrow will appear from the down side
they will stay together for suppose 3 seconds.
they should disappear smoothly disappear together.
(and this loop will continue )

Here somehow I achieved the desired result but only for the first iteration, after it the paragraph is being shown but arrow is not coming.
HTML Page


const messages = document.querySelectorAll('.email-opt-msg');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  message.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(() => {
    arrow.classList.add('visible');
  }, 500);
}

function hideMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  arrow.style.transition = 'opacity 0.3s ease-out';
  arrow.style.opacity = '0';
  message.classList.remove('active');
}

function animateMessages() {
  hideMessage(currentIndex);
  setTimeout(() => {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    showMessage(currentIndex);
    setTimeout(animateMessages, 3000);
  }, 1000);
}

showMessage(0);
setTimeout(animateMessages, 3000);
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.email-opt-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.email-opt-msg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: lightblue;
}

.email-opt-msg.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon-arrow-up {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, transform 0.3s ease-out;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-arrow-up.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.opt-msg-para {
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="email-opt-container">
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up"/>
    <p class="opt-msg-para">30% bessere Chancen auf einen Arbeitsplatz*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up"/>
    <p class="opt-msg-para">42% mehr Rückmeldungen von HR-Teams*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up"/>
    <p class="opt-msg-para">50% bessere Chancen auf den Traumjob*</p>
  </div>
</div>



I want to achieve this output:


when you hideMessage set arrow.style.opacity = '0'; ... you never remove that opacity

Could you explain more exactly what you mean by 'appear smoothly' and 'disappear smoothly' - is it that they are to disappear upwards etc or that they are to go from opacity 1 to 0 etc?

I belive this is what you want:
I changed the code just a little bit to make the animation work
Demo


const messages = document.querySelectorAll('.email-opt-msg');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  message.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(() => {
    arrow.classList.add('visible');
  }, 500);
}

function hideMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  message.classList.remove('active');

  setTimeout(() => {
    arrow.classList.remove('visible');
  }, 500);
}

function animateMessages() {
  hideMessage(currentIndex);
  setTimeout(() => {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
    showMessage(currentIndex);
    setTimeout(animateMessages, 3000);
  }, 1000);
}

showMessage(0);
setTimeout(animateMessages, 3000);
.email-opt-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.email-opt-msg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.email-opt-msg.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon-arrow-up {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, transform 0.3s ease-out;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-arrow-up.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.opt-msg-para {
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="email-opt-container">
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up" />
    <p class="opt-msg-para">30% bessere Chancen auf einen Arbeitsplatz*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up" />
    <p class="opt-msg-para">42% mehr Rückmeldungen von HR-Teams*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email-opt-msg">
    <img class="icon-arrow-up" width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/long-arrow-up.png" alt="long-arrow-up" />
    <p class="opt-msg-para">50% bessere Chancen auf den Traumjob*</p>
  </div>
</div>



I've changed only your hideMessage function.
From:
function hideMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  message.classList.remove('active');

  arrow.classList.remove('visible');
  arrow.style.transform = 'translateY(20px)';
  arrow.style.opacity = '0';
}

To:
function hideMessage(index) {
  const message = messages[index];
  const arrow = message.querySelector('.icon-arrow-up');

  message.classList.remove('active');

  setTimeout(() => {
    arrow.classList.remove('visible');
  }, 500);
}


Hi can you pelase guide me how can change the timing of that frame when the arrow and paragraph both are hidden, right now it seems that they are being hidden for so long.
